# Can i define more than one user group inside the "Group Owner" field for a User Group

Tags: 2013, development, administration, groups

I have a user group inside my sharepoint server 2013 on-premise. now i want to grant 2 users groups to be inside the "Group Owner" field:-

[image]

now seems that i can only define one user or one user group to be inside the "Group Owner" field. so my question is if i can define more than one group to be inside the "Group Owner" field? seems from the UI it is not possible, so can i use power-shell or other means to achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only add one user or one SharePoint group as owner. Its not possible via powershell as well. 
So if you want multiple users as owners, create a new SP group , add your users to it and make it as owner of your group.

`SPGroup.Owner` - Gets or sets the owner for the group, which can be a user or another group.

Reference - [SPGroup.Owner](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spgroup.owner.aspx)

Comment: i already did so, but this is not 100% what i am looking for. as in my case i have a group named "HR Members"+"HR users". where i need both of these groups to be the "Group owner". now as the "HR Members" have Edit permission while the "HR Users" have Contribute permission (lower permission level), so i thought i can assign the "HR Users" to the "HR Members" group and then ass the "HR Members" as the "Group Owner". so in this case the "Group owner" will have the 2 groups users. but seems inside sharepoint i can not assign a group inside another Group. so not sure what i can do on this?

Answer (score 1):

**Resolution A:**
Try adding your global AD group to a SharePoint group and then add the SharePoint group as the owner.

**Resolution B:**
Try creating a new SP group, say Group-Owner and add the users explicitly to the group. Then use this group as the owner of the other group.

Comment: i already did so, but this is not 100% what i am looking for. as in my case i have a group named "HR Members"+"HR users". where i need both of these groups to be the "Group owner". now as the "HR Members" have Edit permission while the "HR Users" have Contribute permission (lower permission level), so i thought i can assign the "HR Users" to the "HR Members" group and then ass the "HR Members" as the "Group Owner". so in this case the "Group owner" will have the 2 groups users. but seems inside sharepoint i can not assign a group inside another Group. so not sure what i can do on this?

Comment: for Resolution A it will not work as we do not have an AD group similar to the groups we have inside sharepoint